# HTTPD Stopped After Install SSL in AWS Linux

Tags: ssl

I have Installed SSL Certificate and When Trying to Restart Httpd It's Goes "Failed"

Here What and How I did

Followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#ssl_enable

and Enable SSL/TLS .Allow Httpd port 443 in Security Groups ( But Page not Opening as HTTPS )

Then I Generate Private Key and CSR Using Command 
"openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr "
Get from ( https://in.godaddy.com/help/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-apache-2x-5269 )

Then I Type "Ls -l " and got the Key and CSR i created . Copy them to /etc/pki/tls/certs/ Directory .Then Input CSR ( typing vi filename.csr anc copy in .txt file) to Godaddy and Got Certificate and Intermediate Certificate Bundle. Also Upload Certificate file & Intermediate Certificate Bundle to /etc/pki/tls/certs/ Directory

Then i edite ssl.conf ( "cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/ then "sudo nanao ssl.conf ) Put # before sslCertificateKeyfile,sslCertificatefile and sslcertificatechainfile Then put my sslcertificateKey,sslCertificatefile and sslcertificatechainfile location and Save ssl.conf

Then Type " sudo service httpd restart" showed me httpd stop : OK and Httpd Start : Failed

Let me know what's Wrong i did . This is 2nd time i tried . First time i though i made mistake may be then re setup server and tried But Same Problem .

Wish someone will help me

Thank You

Comment: Could you give us relevant part of the http daemon logs.

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution . Check Log and got key and csr not matching . then i regenerate key and with new key to generate csr and boom.. it's Done :)